# QuickfixJ - I am getting sec definition details in logs but message.getGroup method fails when I try to retrieve field information

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am getting 35=d message from ICE in my logs with all the details while requesting it via java application which is using quickfixj.
In onMessage implementation I am trying to get group data and values of individual field but my code fails at `getGroup()` and gives the error that field not found.

```java
quickfix.fix44.SecurityDefinition.NoUnderlyings group  = new quickfix.fix44.SecurityDefinition.NoUnderlyings();
message.getGroup(count, group);
```

This getGroup method internally calls getGroups function of quickfixJ which is failing becasuse at below line in  -

```java
this.getGroups(group.getFieldTag()); //group.getFieldTag() is 711 or NoUnderlyings
```

Is there anything that I am missing here? I have tried different ways to get the fields but no luck, help would be much appreciated.

Just an observation - In fromapp /on message method, I am not seeing the full message when I do `message.toString();` . I Only see the first part, Second part which has actual security(many groups) is not being displayed. Not sure if there is any other way(other than `toString()`) to see full message in methods.

Message that I am getting in fromApp/OnMessage on `message.toString();`

> <20190828-12:14:47, FIX.4.4:XXXX/1/0->ICE, incoming> (8=FIX.4.4 9=XXXXX 35=d 49=ICE 34=5 52=20190828-12:14:47.695 56=XXXX 57=1 322=10342 323=4 320=1566994457340_0 393=91 82=1 67=1 9064=0 711=91

**Message that I am getting in logs :**

> <20190828-12:14:47, FIX.4.4:XXXX/1/0->ICE, incoming> (8=FIX.4.4 9=XXXXX 35=d 49=ICE 34=5 52=20190828-12:14:47.695 56=XXXX 57=1 322=10342 323=4 320=1566994457340_0 393=91 82=1 67=1 9064=0 711=91 
>   311=5094981 309=UPL FQF0021.H0021 305=8 463=FXXXXX 307=UK Peak Electricity Futures (Gregorian) - UK Grid - Q1 21 308=IFEU 542=20201230 436=1.0 9013=0.01 9014=1.0 9040=0.01 9041=1.0 9017=1.0 9022=768 9024=1.0 9025=Y 916=20210101 917=20210331 9201=1900 9200=15 9202=Q1 21 9300=8148 9301=IPE UK Grid, UK (Peak) 9302=UK Grid 9303=UPL 998=MWh 9100=GBP 9101=GBP / MWh 9085=hourly 9083=2 9084=0 9061=4639 9062=UK Peak Electricity Futures (Gregorian) 9063=UK Power Peakload Futures (Gregorian) 9032=0.01 9215=1 9216=0 763=800 
>   311=5094980 309=UPL FMH0021! 305=8 463=FXXXXX 307=UK Peak Electricity Futures (Gregorian) - UK Grid - Mar21 308=IFEU 542=20210225 436=1.0 9013=0.01 9014=1.0 9040=0.01 9041=1.0 9017=1.0 9022=276 9024=1.0 9025=Y 916=20210301 917=20210331 9201=1875 9200=12 9202=Mar21 9300=8148 9301=IPE UK Grid, UK (Peak) 9302=UK Grid 9303=UPL 998=MWh 9100=GBP 9101=GBP / MWh 9085=hourly 9083=2 9084=0 9061=4639 9062=UK Peak Electricity Futures (Gregorian) 9063=UK Power Peakload Futures (Gregorian) 9032=0.01 9215=1 9216=0 457=1 458=GB00H1RK4P63 459=U4 763=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of QuickFIX/J are you using? In some older versions the message got truncated when there were unknown fields.
That brings me to the question whether your used data dictionary is really containing all the fields that ICE is sending. Do you have all that 9000+ tags in your dictionary? Please double-check that.